# cs cart - mySQL error on local host

Tags: mysql, cs-cart

I have an issues installing cs-cart on local enviroment, these are the errors:

MySQL settings are not valid
Could not connect to database

I've created a database named cart - and this is the name that I write in the MySQL database name from the installation wizard.

I've created an username and a password for this username - both are filled in correctly.

I have some when I open PhpMyAdmin -

A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.4.14.1, released on 2015-09-08.
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
      Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

I use XAMPP.

Any thoughts on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your config.local.php in the CS-Cart root dir? That file stores your MySQL database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue here.  I first tried adding my own username with no luck.  Next I tried root@localhost after reading here on SF.  Then finally, I tried with username as just: root and it worked.  Install was not very intuitive.  Anyways, I hope this helps someone else.